# WM_CHAR зависимость от раскладки (RU, EN)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться с кодировкой, пожалуйста. (Приложение в Visual C++ 2010. Windows forms applacation).
Приложение должно отправлять заданный текст в окно программы (игра). В предложении содержится и русские буквы и английские. Все бы хорошо, но корректно отправляет сообщение только тогда, когда установлена русская раскладка клавиатуры. Если английская, то приходит такое сообщение - "??????"

Пытался гуглить, но что-то ничего не получается до сих пор.

вот функция отправки сообщения:

void Text_msg (HWND GAME) 
{

```
char * Msg = "Здесь мой текст, hello world";
wchar_t wcMsg[100] = L"";

MultiByteToWideChar(1251, CP_ACP, Msg, -1, wcMsg, MAX_PATH);
for(int k=0; k<=wcslen(wcMsg); k++){
PostMessageW(GAME, WM_CHAR, (wcMsg[k]),0);

}
```

}

В св-вах приложения (Character set) установлен Unicode.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: @maffy271, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В функции у вас установлено: "1251".

```
   MultiByteToWideChar(1251, CP_ACP, Msg, -1, wcMsg, MAX_PATH);
```

Это как раз означает, что корректно будут отправляться русские символы.
Здесь есть полное объяснение, какие бывают параметры вместо 1251 и что каждый из них означает:
[MultiByteToWideChar function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx)
Вам скорее всего подойдёт параметр "CP_UTF8".

Comment: Ну, русской-то нормально отправляются, но только при включенной RU раскладке. Если поставить EN - приходят вопросительные знаки

Comment: Так я вам об этом и гвоорю. Кодировку поменяйте. Сейчас у вас кодировка пропускает только русские буквы!